# NetBeans IDE 7.1 restore functions/methods pane in bottom left hand corner

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.1

For the life of me I cannot find the menu option to restore the functions/methods pane in the bottom left hand corner of the NetBeans IDE. I am using version 7.1.

I have clearly closed it by accident at one point.

Comment: @Sanjay No, I believe it's called the 'Navigator' - see http://apzentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ScreenHunter_13-2012-03-18.jpg

Comment: press `ctrl+7` or goto `Windows` > `navigating` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, to enable the navigator in Netbeans 7.1 :

[image: Here you go :]